# VSTS - login credentials on command line

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2015

I am trying to use *tf.exe get* to retrieve the latest for a workspace.  I'd like to enter my login credentials on the command line.
If I enter this (at a powershell prompt):

```
TFS> . tf.exe get \WorkspaceName\ /login:me@home.local, pAsSwOrD
```

I am prompted for the password for *me@home.local*.

If I enter this:

```
TFS> . tf.exe get \WorkspaceName\ /login:me@home.local,pAsSwOrD
```

I get the message:

> TF30063: You are not authorized to access tfsFileServerName\DefaultCollection.

What's going on?  In the first instance it accepts my username, but not the password; in the second instance it seems to conflate the username and pwd, making it unrecognizable to the server.
Any insight would be appreciated....

Comment: Do you want to login to on-premise TFS or Azure DevOps Service(dev.azure.com/xxxx)?If you use on-premise TFS, which version of TFS do you use? How's the result if you run `tf workspaces` command?

Comment: Try adding your credentials to the credential manager in windows and then don't use /login.  Also make sure you are CD'd in the workspace before executing the command.

Comment: @https://stackoverflow.com/users/5425825/cece-dong-msft
On-premise TFS, TFS version 14.102.25619.0.
If I use the /login: parameter w/o password, I am prompted for the password for whatever login name I provided, so that param seems to be recognized.
When I add my pwd, I get the "You are not authorized...." message.
Is there some very specific formatting for adding the pwd to the command line?
Thanks.
Also: "tf workspaces" seems to work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

If you use on-premise TFS, try to remove the existing credentials from **credential manager**(Control panel > Credential manager), and clear TFS related caches `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\Team Foundation\x.0\Cache`. Also, try to test the command in  Visual Studio command prompt directly to see how's the result.

If you try to work with Azure DevOps, you need to use [OAuth token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/get-started/authentication/oauth?view=azure-devops).